# Scanf parsing string input into array of chars

Tags: c, char, scanf

I want to parse a user-input (using scanf) in 2 separate arrays. g++ compiles without error, but I get a memory-access-error (core dumped).
(in german: "Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)")

```
char *top[10];
char *bottom[10];

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("Karte %d: Obere Werte? ", i );
    scanf( "%s", top[i] );
    printf( "Karte %d: Untere Werte? ", i);
    scanf( "%s", bottom[i] );
}
```

What's the problem here? I tried using `"stringcpy"` with a temp-var `("stringcpy(top[i], temp)")`, but it didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

You haven't allocated memory for your strings. The arguments you give to scanf are uninitialized pointers.

`top[i] = "test"` assigns a pointer to your variable and initializes it with a valid value.

In contrast, `scanf(..., top[i])` tries to write to where `top[i]` points. But `top[i]` isn't initialized and points to some random location, which results in your memory access error.

When you look at [man scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), you can read under

> Conversions
>   ...
>   s
>   Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters;

and now the important part

> the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically.

So you must allocate an array via `malloc()` or declare the character array large enough.

```
char top[10][21];
char bottom[10][21];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("Karte %d: Obere Werte? ", i);
    scanf("%20s",top[i]);
    printf("Karte %d: Untere Werte? ", i);
    scanf("%20s",bottom[i]);
}
```

With

```
scanf("%20s",top[i]);
```

you limit the number of characters read, to prevent a buffer overrun

Comment: but why does 
     top[i] = "test";
work?
can you give me a little bit of example-code plz :) ?

Comment: @user1781595 See the modified answer.

Answer (score 2):

As another answer says, you have to allocate place for your strings. You want an array of top and bottom strings, but with `char * top[10]` you are only allocating room for 10 pointers, not for the characters in the strings. The reason why `top[10] = "Hello"` works is that string literals are implicitly allocated by the compiler, which returns a pointer to those characters.

```
char *top[10], *bottom[10];
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    top[i] = malloc(100); // reserve room for string up to 100 chars
    printf("Karte %d: Obere Werte? ", i);
    scanf("%s",top[i]);
    bottom[i] = malloc(100);
    printf("Karte %d: Untere Werte? ", i);
    scanf("%s",bottom[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an array of pointers. You need to allocate memory for each pointer in array.

You can do the following before `scanf`.

```
top[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*255);
bottom[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*255);
```

After use don't forget to free.

```
free(top[i]);
free(bottom([i]);
```

Comment: if I try this, i get: "Fehler: ungültige Umwandlung von »void*« in »char*« [-fpermissive]"
(in line of "top[i] = malloc(....)"
"invalid conversation of "void*" to "char*" "...

Comment: @user1781595 Compile as C, that complaint indicates you're compiling as C++.